# Get an option ''selected'' based on a $_Session value

Tags: javascript, php, html, session, selected

i am having a platform where every user creates a profile and has to insert his personal info into a DB.One of this is the nationality ,that is being inserted by an HTML drop list (with 100+ countries) when the user is creating his profile for the first time.

```
<select name="nationality" id="nationality" >
            <option value="0" label="Select a country ... " >Select a country ... </option>
```

When the user is loging back in to his profile , i want this dropdown list to have his nationality option marked as  ''selected'' .

Nationality's value is into a $_Session , when all data are being selected  when he logs in .

The most easy way to do this is by using a php code inside every option value like this

```
<option value="GR" label="Greece"   <?php if(($_SESSION['nationality'])=='GR') echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Greece</option>
```

But i can't do this with every option from a list of 300+ countries.I want this to be done by  Javascript .
I've tried many things but i can't sort it out
Thank you in advance

Comment: So... What is your question?

Comment: there is absolutely no code to support all the tags except for "html".

Comment: and if you are indeed using `$_Session`, it's incorrect.

Comment: @ABusyProgrammer I think you may have to submit an "answer" in order to (hopefully) get a response *lol*. I don't think the OP knows quite how Stack rolls.

Comment: You mean that, you have a plain html file containing 100+ options in a select, all written? You may want to get a list of countries in a json, or in your database, then build the select in a *loop*. selecting the chosen country will be trivial then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the session name of the country is the same as the value of the country from the selection list, this should work.

```
<script>
var country = '<?php echo $_SESSION["country"]; ?>';
if(country !== ''){
    document.getElementById("nationality").value = country;
}
</script>
```

Comment: works like magic, thanks a ton bro !! :D :D

Comment: @Panos92 please don't forget to use the checkmark near this answer to mark it as "accepted" if it solves your problem.